# What unix command would I be able to write a Bash Shell script that would create files in a series of directories?

Tags: bash, unix, filesystems, git

I need to write to a shell script that takes a list of directories from file (the directories would be on different lines) and then for each of those filepaths it would create a hidden dummy file ( `.hiddenfile` for example) in each of those directories.

See, the problem I'm trying to solve is to commit empty directories into source control and we're using Git, which, ignores empty files. However, I'd like to know reuse this solution (namely, the part where a script takes a list of directories and creates or edits files in each of those directories) for other problems potentially.

The list of directories would be absolute  like this: `directories.txt`:

```
/Users/johnnydoe/dir1/
/Users/johnnydoe/dir2/subdir2_1/
/Users/johnnydoe/dir3/subdir3_1/subdir3_2/
/Users/johnnydoe/dir4/
...
```

The contents of the `.hiddenfile` would be arbitrary really. It just needs to have something so that git will commit the files like so:

```
# don't leave me out of source control
```

I'm just not sure what Unix command or to use to facilitate this.

I'm using the Mac OS X version of Unix by the way, if that matters.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated in advance.

Comment: Related to the original problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/115983/how-do-i-add-an-empty-directory-to-a-git-repository

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your directory names are more or less sane (spaces are fine) this should work:

```
while read -r n; do \
   echo "# don't leave me out of source control" > "$n"/.hiddenfile; \
done < dirlist.txt
```

This scriptlet will iterate over the list of directories in `dirlist.txt`, saving each line as `$n`. It then uses `echo` to print your desired text into the file `.hiddenfile` in each directory.

Comment: Thanks, terdon! That doesn't look too hard to do. Would it help if I enclosed the directory names in double quotes on the `directories.txt` file?

Comment: The backslashes and the semi-colon are unnecessary.

Comment: @chepner The semicolons are necessary when running from the command line, as are the backslashes to enable direct copy/paste.

Comment: @racl101 No it wouldn't, it would make the whole thing much harder actually. Why would you want to? Unless you have very weird dir names (containing new lines or other weird characters, the script works fine for names with spaces), the script should work.

Comment: The semicolon after `.hiddenfile` is only necessary if you type the whole thing on one line; a newline works just as well. The backslashes are never necessary; newlines are permitted in those places by the bash parser.

Comment: @chepner you're right about the `\ ` in this particular instance because I have cut the command at the right places. I like to include them because it is a good habit to get into, sometimes a command will be cut at the wrong place to fit better into an answer. Same goes for the `;`, I find that using the correct syntax is a good habit, yes in this particular instance the `;` after `.hiddenfile` _can_ be omitted but I tend to write this kind of command on one line so I am used to it. In any case, it is better to include it to avoid errors if the OP modifies the command in any way.

Answer (score 0):

xargs works really well for executing a command for every argument in a list.

e.g (cygwin, OS X has xargs too):

```
$ find ~/tmp/ -type d | xargs.exe -Iz  echo echo $RANDOM \> "z/.hidden"   |sh
$ find ~/tmp -type f -name \.hidden |head -n4
/home/jaroslav/tmp/.hidden
/home/jaroslav/tmp/Data/.hidden
/home/jaroslav/tmp/Data/Meshes/.hidden
/home/jaroslav/tmp/Data/Meshes/actors/.hidden
```

`find ~/tmp -type d` can be replaced by `cat /path/dirlist.txt`

First part of the pipe generates a list of directories. Second part creates a command what would echo a random number (bash) and write it to a file in the found directory. Last part of the pipe executes those commands.

Answer (score 0):

A "one"-liner using `tee`:

```
echo "# don't leave me out of source control" |
 tee $( while read -r; do echo "$REPLY/.hiddenfile"; done < directories.txt) \
 > /dev/null
```